# Creating Demo of App

Tags: java, git, grails

I've developed a java/grails web application that has all it's components stored on a single development server and the source code is currently maintained by SVN. I want to port/prepare this application to an CentOS instance in virtualbox on my laptop for demonstration purposes. The problem is there are multiple configuration files that have the development server's ip address, now obivously, this will have to be changed to the ip address of the CentOS instance. *What is the best way for me to port/prepare my app?*

I was thinking, after I've created a git repo from the svn repo, I could create a git branch entitled "demo", wherein I could make the necessary changes to the config files and generate the needed jars as usual via maven2.

Note:

1. I would like to move from SVN to GIT
2. I'm using maven2 as the 'build' tool (I'm thinking of moving to buildr or gradle)

Comment: @jforberg: I'm aware of the DRY principle. My application is comprised of a grails 'front-end' with various flex modules, and a java web service as the 'back-end'. As a result of this modularity there is inherent need of multiple configuration files. Furthermore, since this app is still in the development phase, all the components are on the same server and thus refer to the same IP. When the app is moved into production that will obviously change.

Answer (score 3):

You have a lot of goals, my advice is "don't try to do multiple things at once if they interfere with each other".

Moving SVN to GIT is not a bad idea, but it buys you nothing in terms of getting you IP address configuration issues worked out.  In fact, an upset in how you submit code (meaning any change) will just slow you down as everyone learns the new submission process.

Moving maven2 to some other build tool will impact the build for the same reasons.  Don't get me wrong, there are advantages to using one build tool over another, but it is far more reasonable to wait till a tool fails you prior to making the decision to pull the trigger.

Your app should have been built with the flexibility to move it to another machine "built in".  That's the highest priority, and the issue you should fix first.  Then you can afford to tinker with a different development process (which is what you will get with different source code control and build tools).

Comment: While I do generally agree with your advice, I don't believe it applies in this scenario since *the* goal is to port my app for demoing. Moving from SVN to GIT and Maven2 to Buildr/Gradle are tertiary concerns that I was planning on implementing at a later time. However, if those changes could/would facilitate the porting of my app, then I figured I'd do them now, rather than later.

Comment: Furthermore, I agree that my app should be "flexible" enough to move to other machines. And I've tried to make my app such, the problem is that the various components: activemq, flex modules, grails front-end require the ip address of the server providing the services. Lastly, part of the purpose of this question is to get insight/feedback on how I can make my app more flexible to deploy to various machines.

Comment: @Dan, It sounds like you have a number of independent components loosely coupled together.  That is good for some tasks, and bad for others.  Single point configuration is much easier for a monolithic program, but it can still be done (if you choose to do so) in a highly component oriented environment.  The trick is to have all of your components query the correct configuration from a central store.  Perhaps the right answer for now is simply to invest in really good installation documentation.  Once you have the instructions, you have the ability to consider automating it.

Answer (score 0):

you have two solution

or make a branch with SVN (svn supports it)

or you can use maven to read the parameters from a properties file, and make two profiles to read a properties file for demo and local enviorment

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <files>
                    <file>${env}.properties</file>
                </files>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and the profiles:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <env>local</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>demo</id>
        <activation>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <env>demo</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```